# Grouping counts into overlapping categories

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm looking to group counts into categories of (0+, 5+, 10+, 15+, etc.)

So an agent with 7 leads should be counted in the 0+, 5+ groups, but not 10+, 15+.

Postgres Query:

```
WITH agent_stats AS (
    SELECT agent_id, FLOOR(COUNT(*)/5) AS count_category
    FROM leads
    GROUP BY 1
)

SELECT count_category, COUNT(*)
FROM agent_stats
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1
```

Result:

```
| count_category | count |
| 0              | 12    |
| 5              | 18    |
| 15             | 9     |
| 20             | 4     |
```

Desired:

```
| count_category | count |
| 0              | 43    |
| 5              | 31    |
| 15             | 13    |
| 20             | 4     |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is probably a cumulative sum:

```
WITH agent_stats AS (
    SELECT agent_id, FLOOR(COUNT(*)/5) AS count_category
    FROM leads
    GROUP BY 1
)
SELECT count_category, COUNT(*),
       SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER (ORDER BY count_category DESC)
FROM agent_stats
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1;
```